# Does calling new [] twice on the same pointer without calling delete [] in between cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I've heard that you should usually "delete" whenever you use "new", yet when I run a simple test program (below), it doesn't seem to make a difference which numbers I put for arraySize or numLoops. Does this cause a memory leak?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double *array;
    const int arraySize = 100000;
    const int numLoops = 100000;

    for (int i = 0; i < numLoops; i++)
    {
        // do I need to call "delete [] array;" here?
        array = new double[arraySize];
    }

    int x;
    std::cin >> x; // pause the program to view memory consumption

    delete [] array;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only the last of the allocated arrays is deleted again in this example, so YES, the rest of the arrays WILL leak and NO, this is not sufficient.

Comment: Try not to ask multiple questions with opposite answers, specifically "Does ... cause a memory leak?" has the opposite answer to "Is this usage of delete [] sufficient?"

Comment: @Platinum: Sorry, Steve is spot on, the "yes" was referring to "Does ... cause a memleak?"

Comment: I edited the question to only include the "does it leak?" formulation, as all the answers so far seem to refer to that.

Comment: @Anthony have you actually tested this? And, did it allocate 80 GB?

Comment: Sorry, I will avoid opposite questions in the future.

Comment: Whenever I view the program in task manager, it just says 712 KB! Is there a better way to test memory consumption?

Comment: You can use valgrind on Linux systems. Very simple and informative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not sufficient.

Each time you call `new` or `new[]`, some memory is allocated, and you are given the address of that memory (in order to be able to use it).  Each piece of memory must eventually be `delete`d (or `delete[]`d).

You are storing that address in `array`, but then immediately overwriting it on the next iteration.  Therefore you have no way of `delete`-ing all of pieces of memory that you've been allocated.  Therefore you have a memory leak.

Comment: Would malloc and realloc do the trick and get alla the memory freed with a single delete? I mean allocate some memory at the beginning and expand it after with realloc.

Answer (score 4):

It helps to understand correctly what you are actually *doing*.

You are not calling `new[]` twice on the same pointer. You are calling `new[]` twice, and storing both results into the same pointer. `new[]` simply returns a pointer to the allocated memory. To avoid leaking memory, you have to free that memory again at some point. But the pointer is not the memory, it is just a pointer telling you where the allocated memory *is*.

So you can always overwrite the pointer, setting it to point to a new, different address. And then you just lost all knowledge of where it *used* to point to. If it used to point to memory that you ought to free, then you can no longer find that chunk of memory, so you can no longer call `delete[]` on it, and so... it is leaked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You don't call `new` on a pointer, you call `new` and it returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  You are responsible for holding onto that pointer and deleting it.  If you overwrite that value, as you are, you are leaking.

Comment: +1 for being concise. And think about adding a note about garbage collection in other OOP languages like Java or C#.

Comment: @TheBlastOne Is Java/C# garbage collection really crucial to the OP's understanding for this question? I'm not so sure.

Comment: @TheBlastOne: if he added that, the answer would no longer be concise.

Answer (score 2):

Two questions, two answers.

Question one: Does calling new [] twice on the same pointer without calling delete [] in between cause a memory leak?

Answer one:  Not always, but 99% of the time yes.  The code below calls new twice, with the pointer to array, but the first time it assigns the address of the allocated memory to array2, and the second time it keeps the address to itself.  It is possible to delete both array in this scenario.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double *array;
    double *array2;
    const int arraySize = 100000;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        // do I need to call "delete [] array;" here?
        array = new double[arraySize];
        if(i == 0)
        {
            array2 = array;
        }
    }

    int x;
    std::cin >> x; // pause the program to view memory consumption

    delete [] array;
    delete [] array2;

    return 0;
}
```

Question Two: Is this usage of delete [] sufficient?

Answer Two: no, because the delete call only influences the address pointed to by the pointer you've given it.  As you overwrote the pointer in your example, it deletes the last allocated section of memory

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you `new` (or `new[]`) memory you *must* `delete` (or `delete[]`) it or it will leak.

Each time you call new you get returned a pointer to the heap allocated object if the `new` operation succeeds. If the pointer to this memory goes out of scope or is reassigned (i.e. what you are doing here) then you will be *unable* to delete the memory later.

In your code example, only the last allocated memory will be destroyed. You can use something like process explorer or even task manager to check for memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Fortunately, there's a better way -- instead of allocating the memory directly, use `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    double *array;
    const int arraySize = 100000;
    const int numLoops = 100000;

    for (int i = 0; i < numLoops; i++)
    {
       std::vector<double> array(arraySize);
       // use it just like a normal array
    }

    int x;
    std::cin >> x; // pause the program to view memory consumption
    return 0;
}
```

The `vector` will be destroyed (and the memory it controls released) each iteration of the loop.

You shouldn't generally use `new` unless you really need to. I'd go so far as to say there's *never* a need (or even good reason) to use the array form of `new`.