# Is calling new twice on the same vtkSmartPointer unsafe?

Tags: c++, vtk

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979776/does-calling-new-twice-on-the-same-pointer-without-calling-delete-in-betwe) question you cannot call new twice on the same normal pointer without a delete, but what if you are working with the `vtkSmartPointer`s? I had several occations where calling Delete() on such a smart pointer gave a segmentation error even though a New() was declared after it.
How can I completely destroy the object and create a new one? I need this to destroy the vtkRenderWindow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: New is not applied to a pointer. New delivers a pointer.

Comment: Why does it point to same location then after calling new again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vtkSmartPointers should be safe to overwrite as their purpose is to clean up the allocated memory on their own when they are destructed. However, if any other copy of the smart pointer remains the window will not get destroyed immediately when you overwrite the "original" smart pointer.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> rw;
rw = vtkRenderWindow<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
rw = vtkRenderWindow<vtkRenderWindow>::New(); // destructor of previous instance is invoked, which deletes the pointer
```